# Problem with linking one file containing namespace definition with another using that namespace in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, static-linking

I have two files once is named as test.cpp and another as ani.cpp.

**test.cpp is as follows:**

```
#include<iostream>

namespace Anirudh{

    void start(){
        std::cout<<"This is the start function of the namespace Anirudh\n";
    }
}
```

and the file **ani.cpp is as follows**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace Anirudh;
int main(){

    start();
    return 0;
}
```

**and this is what I am doing on the terminal**

```
anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Desktop/testing$ g++ -c test.cpp
anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Desktop/testing$ g++ test.o ani.cpp 
ani.cpp:3: error: ‘Anirudh’ is not a namespace-name
ani.cpp:3: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
ani.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ani.cpp:6: error: ‘start’ was not declared in this scope
anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Desktop/testing$
```

This is the first time I am trying to define my own namespace in C++ and using it in another code. I got my code running after `#include "test.cpp"` in my `ani.cpp` file but I want to link the object code of `test.cpp` with `ani.cpp` rather than including it inside ani.cpp
I have even tried extern namespace Anirudh; but that didn't work. Of-course there is a proper way to link them which I do not know right now. So please enlighten me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What resource are you using to learn C++? Does a "header file" ring any bells? That's pretty much the base of modular programming in C and C++. Even the worse C++ books (e.g. the ones that acutally teach C with classes) should include this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within `ani.cpp` you never told the compiler that there's a `namespace Anirudh` somewhere else in the program prior to doing the `using`. If you're used to other module systems this probably seems quirky.

What you can do is declare the namespace+function prior to calling it, with these lines before the `using namespace` in `ani.cpp`

```
namespace Anirudh{    
    void start();
}
```

Often these declarations would be wrapped up in a header but that's probably not needed for this simple example.

Comment: I disagree that it's not needed. Better get used to headers early, they are a time (and redundancy) saver in everything larger than two files.

Comment: @delnan: I think a beginner like me should try everything. I am used to using headers for my C programming exercises.

Answer (score 0):

What about prototyping the function a la:

```
namespace Anirudh {
    void start();
} // namespace Anirudh

int main(...){
//...
```

Comment: Thanks buddy!!! It did the work for me. I didn't knew the way to declare namespaces.

Comment: @Everyone: this is ridiculous. I am trying to accept the answer and its asking me to wait for 4 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have header file, then the least you've to do is : write the prototype of your function in `ani.cpp` before calling it as,

```
using namespace Anirudh;

void Anirudh::start();

int main(){

    start();
    return 0;
}
```